# Finding length of array inside a function

Tags: c, arrays

In the program below the length of the array `ar` is correct in main but in `temp` it shows the length of the pointer to `ar` which on my computer is 2 (in units of `sizeof(int)`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void temp(int ar[]) // this could also be declared as `int *ar`
{
    printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(ar)/sizeof(int));
}

int main(void)
{
    int ar[]={1,2,3};
    printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(ar)/sizeof(int));
    temp(ar);
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to know how I should define the function so the length of the array is read correctly in the function.

Comment: The best way to probably do it would be to add an extra parameter that takes the size of the array, i.e. `void temp(int *ar, size_t len);`

Comment: @Th3Cuber from what I understand he wants the length as the result.

Comment: Because sizeof operator computer size at `compilation` time so, it can't be dynamic. you have to pass it explicitly. Read here: [sizeof is a compile time operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Using_sizeof_with_arrays)

Comment: Why don't you want to use strlen() for this purpose?

Comment: strlen() only works on strings, not arrays of integers, isn't this correct?

Comment: @Ishmeet `strlen` counts the number of chars before a `\0`, not the capacity of the array.

Comment: @weston that was what I meant, we have to use \0 in the array at the last element, then we can determine size using strlen()

Comment: Sooooooooo many dupeeeeeees!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no 'built-in' way to determine the length inside the function. However you pass `arr`, `sizeof(arr)` will always return the pointer size. So the best way is to pass the number of elements as a seperate argument. Alternatively you could have a special value like `0` or `-1` that indicates the end (like it is `\0` in strings, which are just `char []`).
But then of course the 'logical' array size was `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) - 1`

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion! I will try to do it like that. In my program the values in the array have to be positive, so I will add a negative value. But then the problem is this: how can I add a negative value in the end of the array before hand and without knowing how many elements it has in it?

Comment: In your example you would declare `int ar[] = { 1, 2, 3, -1 };`. In a more complex situation you could e.g. initialize your complete array with -1 in a loop before filling it.

Comment: *`'logical' array size was sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) - 1`* **NO** array size is: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)` , use `-1` for highest index.

Comment: @Grijesh that's why I wrote "'logical'". Think about `strlen()` where '\0' isn't counted either.

Answer (score 13):

Don't use a function, use a macro for this:

```
//Adapted from K&R, p.135 of edition 2.
#define arrayLength(array) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((array)[0]))

int main(void)
{
    int ar[]={1,2,3};
    printf("%d\n", arrayLength(ar));
    return 0;
}
```

You still cannot use this macro inside a function like your `temp` where the array is passed as a parameter for the reasons others have mentioned.

Alternative if you want to pass one data type around is to define a type that has both an array and capacity:

```
typedef struct
{
  int *values;
  int capacity;
} intArray;

void temp(intArray array)
{
  printf("%d\n", array.capacity);
}

int main(void)
{
    int ar[]= {1, 2, 3};
    intArray arr;
    arr.values = ar;
    arr.capacity = arrayLength(ar);
    temp(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

This takes longer to set up, but is useful if you find your self passing it around many many functions.

Comment: Thanks, but the macro also doesn't work in the function. If I wanted this job to be done in main() there would be no problem from the beginning.

Comment: @astroboy fair enough, I've put another suggestion too.

Comment: This is an interesting method. I will certainly consider it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

As others have said the obvious solution is to pass the length of array as parameter, also you can store this value at the begin of array

```
#include <stdio.h>

void temp(int *ar)
{
    printf("%d\n", ar[-1]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int ar[]= {0, 1, 2, 3};
    ar[0] = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]) - 1;
    printf("%d\n", ar[0]);
    temp(ar + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

When you write `size(ar)` then you're passing a **pointer** and **not an array**.

The size of a pointer and an int is 4 or 8 - depending on *ABI* (Or, as @H2CO3 mentioned - something completely different), so you're getting `sizeof(int *)/sizeof int` (4/4=1 for 32-bit machines and 8/4=2 for 64-bit machines), which is 1 or 2 (Or.. something different).

Remember, in C when pass an array as an argument to a function, you're passing a pointer to an array.
If you want to pass the size of the array, you should pass it as a separated argument.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand that, I just wanted to see if there is really no way to do it inside the function, without adding to the parameters.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun I written same answer very first but it doesn't answer hence deleted, Read my comment to the question.

Comment: "The size of a pointer and an int is 4 or 8" - or something completely different. This can be explained very nicely without making incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's enough to say that you can have two different values to clarify my point, however, I'll add this so it'll be better.

Comment: "*you're passing a pointer to an array.*" no quite right. If an array is passed to a function it "decays" to a pointer to its 1st element. By address this is the same as the pointer to the array, by type it definitely isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could do this using a function. It will always return  length of the pointer rather than the length of the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the array up into a struct:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct foo {int arr[5];};
struct bar {double arr[10];};

void temp(struct foo f, struct bar g)
{
    printf("%d\n",(sizeof f.arr)/(sizeof f.arr[0]));
    printf("%d\n",(sizeof g.arr)/(sizeof g.arr[0]));
}

void main(void)
{
    struct foo tmp1 = {{1,2,3,4,5}};
    struct bar tmp2;
    temp(tmp1,tmp2);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function ar is a pointer so the sizeof operator will return the length of a pointer.  The only way to compute it is to make ar global and or change its name.  The easiest way to determine the length is size(array_name)/(size_of(int). The other thing you can do is pass this computation into the function.