# c only first 8 bytes passed to function

Tags: c, micropython

I am working on a C module in micropython... if I pass a byte array to a function, only the first 8 bytes make it (according to sizeof). I have to also send in the length, then copy it to access everything in a function.

```
static void printSomeBytes(char *description, byte *bytes)
{    
    printf("\r\n%s: ", description);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(bytes); ++i )
    {
        printf("%02X", bytes[i]); 
    }
}

static void printAllBytes(char *description, byte *bytes, int length)
{    
    byte copy[length];
    memcpy(copy, bytes, length);

    printf("\r\n%s: ", description);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(copy); ++i )
    {
        printf("%02X", copy[i]); 
    }

    // this also works without making a copy 
    //for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i )
    //{
    //    printf("%02X", bytes[i]); 
    //}
}

byte Kifd[] = { 0x0B, 0x79, 0x52, 0x40, 0xCB, 0x70, 0x49, 0xB0, 0x1C, 0x19, 0xB3, 0x3E, 0x32, 0x80, 0x4F, 0x0B};

printSomeBytes("Kifd", kifd); // prints "Kifd: 0B795240CB7049B0"
printAllBytes("Kifd", kifd, sizeof(kifd)); // prints "Kifd: 0B795240CB7049B01C19B33E32804F0B"
```

What am I doing wrong / is there a better way to send a pointer to a byte array to a function?

Comment: Detail: With `printAllBytes("Kifd", kifd, sizeof(kifd))`, the function does not receive a "a pointer to a byte array" but a "pointer to the first element of the byte array" a `byte*`.    `&Kifd` is a "pointer to a byte array".  Same effective address - different types

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding length of array inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590226/finding-length-of-array-inside-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(bytes)` returns you the number of bytes that a pointer to `byte` will need to be stored in memory. It doesn't return you the number of bytes that the array pointed to by `bytes` contains.

For that you need to pass that size to the function:

```
static void printSomeBytes(char *description, byte *bytes, size_t size)
{
    printf("\r\n%s: ", description);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        printf("%02X", bytes[i]); 
    }

    puts("");

}
```

<sup>**edit**</sup>
I also added `puts("")` there so that the bytes are printed right away. Note
that `printf` is buffered and it won't show the output on the screen unless you flush it
(`fflush(stdout);`) by hand or add a `'\n'` newline at the end of `printf`.
`puts(string)` is equivalent to `printf("%s\n", string);` but without the
overhead of having to parse the format argument.
<sup>**end edit**</sup>

And then call it:

```
byte Kifd[] = { 0x0B, 0x79, 0x52, 0x40, 0xCB, 0x70, 0x49, 0xB0, 0x1C, 0x19, 0xB3, 0x3E, 0x32, 0x80, 0x4F, 0x0B};

printSomeBytes("Kifd", Kifd, sizeof Kifd / sizeof *Kifd);
```

Also the correct way of getting the number of elements of an array is:

```
sizeof array / sizeof *array
```

I encourage you to use that formula even when you know that the type is 8bit
long. It makes the code more portable.

Comment: Might as well use `for (size_t i = 0;...`  and `printf("%02hhX",`

Comment: @chux Oh yeah, my bad, I just made copy&paste and changed the condition without looking further. I fixed my answer, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

You've done a poor job of explaining the issue. Are you saying that `sizeof(bytes)` returns 8?

`bytes` is a pointer, and `sizeof(bytes)` is returning the size of that pointer. And pointers may be 8 bytes on your system. That has nothing to do with the number of bytes at the address it points to.

In C, when you get a pointer, there is no way to know how many bytes it points to unless you provide that information as another argument or have a special terminating value in the data.