# Why is sizeof not returning the correct number of elements in array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, argv

So for practice, I wrote a little code that takes a variable number of integers in an array and then determines the largest value.

I wanted to make the program runnable from the command line (i.e. `findMax 4, 5, 6, 20, 1, 3` in that exact format).

So considering that `argv[1]` is a pointer to a `char` array, I figure I can loop from `argv[1][0]` to `argv[1][n]`.

I think the pointers are the reason I am not able to get my code to work.
In the first code, I wrote, using

```
sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) = # of elements in array 'arr'
```

correctly gave me the number of elements.
However, when I run

```
sizeof(argv[1]) / sizeof(argv[1][0]) = always return (integer) 4
```

Am I correct in thinking that I am using a pointer here, which is why the size is always the same? I tried to dereference both of them (separately and together) but it created even more confusing results.

Here is the full code which is not working. **Except** for some odd reason, it only works when I enter exactly **two** numbers (i.e. findMax.exe 2, 3 will correctly determine that '3' is the largest number).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf ("Finding largest value from input: %s", argv[1]);

    int size = (int)sizeof(argv[1]) / (int)sizeof(argv[1][0]);
    int x = 0;
    int next;
    int biggest = 0;

    while (x < size) {
        if (argv[1][x] != ',') {
            next = argv[1][x];
            printf("\n%c", (int)next);
            if ((int)next > biggest) {
                biggest = next;
            }   
        }
        x++;
    }
    printf("\nBiggest # is: %c", biggest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `argv[1]` is a pointer and not an array.

Comment: Because that's not what `sizeof` does.

Comment: `sizeof` is determined at compile time. The number of characters in `argv[1]` is determined at runtime. Therefore you will never be able to know the value of `size` at compile time -- you have to actually inspect the string in `argv[1]`, either by looking at every character or by using a library function that does so.

Comment: `while (x < size) {` is not needed anyways.  Suggest `while (argv[1][x]) {`

Comment: Please see [c, finding length of array inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590226/c-finding-length-of-array-inside-a-function)

Comment: thats what argc is for

Comment: You may want to try passing each number separately with spaces between them instead of commas.  Then you don’t have to manually separate them.

Comment: @DanielPryden In case you have a variable length array `sizeof` is not determined at compile time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C sizeof a passed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array)

Comment: regarding: `sizeof(argv[1]) / sizeof(argv[1][0] `  this is saying the size of a pointer (argv[1]) divided by the size of a character.  It seems a pointer is 4 bytes on your architecture) so 4 / 1 = 4  To get the length of the `argv[1]`, use: `size_t length = strlen( argv[1] );`

Answer (score 4):

`argv[1]` is of type `char *`, a pointer to a character. The `sizeof` operator gives you only the size of a pointer on your system. `argv[1][0]` is of type `char` and therefore its size is `1`.

It works for two numbers because "2,3" has four chars (including null-terminator), which is coincidently the same as the size of a pointer on your platform.

What you need to do is to determinate the length of `argv[1]` at runtime with the `strlen` function.

```
int size = strlen(argv[1]);
```

But there are other things that may cause problems:

If you don't pass any arguments to your function the behavior is undefined since `argv[1]` does not exist. You should check `argc` how much arguments were passed.

The `int` typecast you made does not read in an integer till the next `,` as your example usage may suggest.

Here is a program that should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int next, biggest=INT_MIN;
    char *token;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong arguments.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char input[strlen(argv[1])+1];
    strcpy(input, argv[1]);

    printf ("Finding largest value from input: %s\n\n",argv[1]);

    token = strtok(input, ",");

    while(token)
    {
        next = atoi(token);
        if(next>biggest)
        {
            biggest = next;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");   
    }

    printf("Biggest # is: %d\n",biggest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps better as `int size = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;`

Comment: @WeatherVane `int size = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;` is good to go with the idea of _size_, yet then `next = argv[1][x];` will lastly do `next = '\0';`

Comment: @chux oops, i'd expect 1 arg so argc=2.  looks like op is walking the characters in the first arg with x.  (my silly suggestion deleted)

Comment: Minor: By starting with `int biggest=INT_MIN;`, code can properly report on "a variable number of integers" with input like `"findMax -4,-5,-6"`.

Comment: @chux I thought of that too, but wanted to stick to OPs approach. Anyway it is for sure better if someone wants to handle negative values. I will change my answer, thanks.

Comment: Note that `agv[1]` is modifiable and so a copy is not required.  Still a copy, IMO, is more robust than taking advantage of this C "feature" of a modifiable `argv[]`.

Comment: @chux Yes it is probably worth to mention. The reason why i copied `argv[1]` is because after finding the max value there is no chance that you can access the elements again.

Answer (score 2):

In fact `argv[1]` is a pointer to a `char`, not an array of `char`. And considering a pointer is 4 in size in your platform and a `char` is surely 1 byte, then 4 is the logical answer to this:

```
sizeof(argv[1]) / sizeof(argv[1][0])
     4          /        1
```

One main problem with your code is that you're not parsing the integers. You are comparing characters. In `10,2`, the biggest will be `2`.

Note that there is no need to find the size of a string at all if the intention is to iterate char by char up to it's end. You can just do it until a null is found. This strategy however might not be the easiest though, if you do want to parse the characters.

A completely different approach involving no array or size checking could use `strtok` and `strtol` to parse the string into tokens and integers. Here follows a very simple implementation with no error checking at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int curr, max = 0;
    char *token;

    token = strtok(argv[1], ",");

    while (token != NULL) {
        curr = (int)strtol(token, (char **)NULL, 10);
        if (curr > max) max = curr;
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    printf("The biggest integer was: %d\n", max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @snr Isn't it? What is it then?

Comment: It's my fault. Here is too night. Sorry everybody. Have nice night! That's all from me!

Comment: @sidyll More precisely spoken, arrays decay to pointers when they are passed as function arguments.