# helper function using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to implement a helper function that sums the ints in a given array, and then changing the "array_sum" variable in the main function using pointers NOT RETURNING AN INT IN HELPER FUNCTION. However, I get the following error, "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" any help would me much appreciated

```
void get_sum(int array[], int* array_sum)
{
    int length = sizeof(array)-1;
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){      
        *array_sum+= array[i];
    }   
}
main()
{
  int array_sum;
  int my_array[] = {25, 18, 6, 47, 2, 73, 100};

  get_sum(my_array, array_sum);

  printf("sum = %d", array_sum);

}
```

Expected result:

sum = 271

actual result:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Turn on all warnings, and use a recent compiler. E.g. try running this on https://wandbox.org. (Pick language "C", compiler "GCC", conformance mode "C11", and "-pedantic-errors".)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding length of array inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590226/finding-length-of-array-inside-a-function)

Comment: Additionally to the answer given below you need to pass the address to the variable `array_sum` in line `get_sum(my_array, array_sum);` like so `get_sum(my_array, &array_sum);`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `array_sum` by value when the function expects its address. The segmentation fault occurs because the lines in the function where you dereference `array_sum` will try to treat its value as a memory address.

Also, when an array is passed as an argument to a function, it decays into a pointer to its first element, losing length information. `sizeof` will not give you the length of the array in this case.

You may either pass a “length” parameter to the function or use a sentinel value at the end of the array to indicate to the function when to stop processing the array.  The former option is the least hassle.

Answer (score 1):

The function `get_sum` expects a pointer to an `int` for the second parameter, but you're passing an `int` instead.  Your compiler should have warned you about this.

As a result, the current value of `array_sum` (which is indeterminate because it has not been initialized) is treated as a pointer value which your function subsequently dereferences.  Dereferencing an invalid pointer (as well as reading an uninitialized value) invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case causes a crash.

You need to pass the *address* of `array_sum` to the function.  This gives you a pointer to an `int` which matches what the function expects so you can modify the value in the function.

```
get_sum(my_array, &array_sum);
```

Also, unrelated to this, the following inside of `get_sum` is not correct:

```
int length = sizeof(array)-1;
```

The parameter `array` is not actually an array but a pointer to the first element of an array.  So `sizeof(array)` gives you the size of a pointer.  You might get away with it in this *particular* case because, assuming a pointer is 8 bytes on your system, `length` gets set to 7 which happens to be the number of elements of the array `my_array` in `main`.  If you added or removed elements things would suddenly break.

The proper way to handle this is to get the size of the actual array in `main` and pass it to your function.  So the function would look like this:

```
void get_sum(int array[], int* array_sum, int length)
```

And you call it like this:

```
int my_array[] = {25, 18, 6, 47, 2, 73, 100};
int len = sizeof(my_array)/sizeof(my_array[0]);

get_sum(my_array, &array_sum, len);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array decay to pointer to it's first element when passed as argument to a function, in you're case

```
sizeof(array) = sizeof(int*) = 8
```

but I think the segmentation fault is not from that line as it happens that my_array has exactly 7 elements, and the length calculated in the get_sum function is also (coincidence) 7.
first of all you need to initialize array_sum, and replace the line

```
get_sum(my_array, array_sum);
```

by

```
get_sum(my_array, &array_sum);
```