# Are array lengths calculated differently when passed onto functions?

Tags: c, arrays, function, size, calculation

I really do not understand why the function and the calculation in main does not give the same answer.

The function prints 1 and the calculation in main prints 8 - the correct size:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void size(const int a[]) {
  printf("%i\n",sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));
}

 int main(void) {
  int array[] = { 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 7, 3, 3 };
  printf("%i\n", (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])));
  size(array);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Comment: Also see [finding-length-of-array-inside-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590226/finding-length-of-array-inside-a-function) and [c-sizeof-a-passed-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array)

Answer (score 2):

You get an incorrect size inside that function because of [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

Your array becomes a pointer when you pass it to a function and `sizeof(pointer) / sizeof(arr[0])` will give you 1 because in your current architecture configuration, size of a pointer is 4 bytes and size of an integer is also 4 bytes.

But that's not the case when you deal with the original array inside your main function, so you get the correct output there.

Comment: That's not the best link. Usually GeeksForGeeks presents incorrect examples or things that "work" but have undefined behavior.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I know, I link gfg when I feel that the OP is a beginner :P Anyways, since you have a decent reputation, feel free to edit my answer :)  I'm having a bad day on SO lol

Comment: ... and I agree with you both :)