# how to use sizeof() for reference_to_array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

How to use `sizeof()` to determine the size of a reference to an array?

I have declared an array in `main()` and used `sizeof()` to print its total size it has occupied.

And then I pass the array to a function as a reference to the array, but I am unable to use `sizeof()` for the reference (array) variable.

```
#include <iostream>

double sum(double (&list)[], size_t size);

int main(){
    double arr[]{34.5, 67.8, 92.345, 8.1234, 12.314, 3.4};
    double result{};

    std::cout << "size of the array : " << sizeof(arr) << std::endl;
    result = sum(arr, std::size(arr));
    std::cout << "the total is " << result << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}

double sum(double (&list)[], size_t size){
    double total{};
    std::cout << "the size is : " << sizeof(list) << std::endl;

    for( int i{} ; i < size ; i++){
        total += list[i];
    }
    
    return total;
}
```

`sizeof(list)` shows a compiler error:

```
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘double []’
     std::cout << "the size is : " << sizeof(list) << std::endl;
```

After changing the function parameter as `double (&list)[6]` I get the output I want, but why is `sizeof(list)` not working like `sizeof(arr)` when `list` is declared without explicitly mentioning its size in the declaration, though it's a reference?

Comment: *how to use sizeof() to determine the size of a reference to an array.*  You don't.  That's not what `sizeof` is for.  You'll need to pass the size of the array as a parameter.  Or use `std::array`.  Or use `std::vector`.  Or use the template technique for references to arrays.  Or use the C++ idiomatic begin and end as iterator parameters to the function, from which you can calculate the size.

Comment: The proper C++ answer is _don't use C style arrays_. Use `std::array`, `std::vector`,  `std::span`, or iterators as applicable. Do note that that use of `sizeof` isn't the only problem with this code. Ever if you "fix" it, you'd still get a "no known conversion from 'double[6]' to 'double (&)[]'" error

Comment: re: _"but why sizeof(list) is not working like sizeof(arr)"_, see [Finding length of array inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17590226/11082165) and [How do I find the length of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4108313/11082165) and [When a function has a specific-size array parameter, why is it replaced with a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1328223/11082165)

Comment: In `main`, print out the value of `std::size(arr), and compare it with `sizeof(arr)`. They do two different things.

Comment: You can't create a reference to an array of unknown size. If you want the function to accept an array of any size, you need to use a template (`template <size_t N> double sum(double (&list)[N]);`) or a pointer (`double sum(double *list, size_t size);`) instead of a reference.

Comment: TLDR not, stop using "C" style arrays and just use `std::vector<double>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a C-style array is part of its type, so an array declared as `double arr[6];` has type `(double)[6].` which is a complete type.

The `sizeof` operator works at compile-time. When you use `sizeof` on an array, it returns the size of the array in bytes. This is possible because the size of the array is part of its type and the compiler knows it at compile time.

However, if you attempt to use `sizeof` on an incomplete type such as `(double)[]`, this will result in compilation error, as the type of the argument to `sizeof` has to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++ I would expect code like this without any sizeof :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

double sum(const std::vector<double>& values)
{
    double sum{ 0.0 };

    // IF you want to write loops, prefer using range based for loops (they will 'know' the size of values)
    for (const auto value : values)
    {
        sum += value;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> values{ 34.5, 67.8, 92.345, 8.1234, 12.314, 3.4 };
    double result = sum(values);

    // no need to use sizeof in current C++, just ask the vector
    std::cout << "size of the array : " << values.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "the total is " << result << "\n";

    // or to write code with no loops (in your code) at all
    std::cout << "the total using accumulate is " << std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0.0);

    return 0;
}
```